# Image appearing as <Binary data> in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, image

I want to store an image in sql server using C# , the data type of my field is **image**  and so I am passing a byte array to the image fields and all I get on all the records is **Binary data**.
Is this how it is supposed to work or what?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: _Binary data_ = _byte array_

Comment: `image` is depreciated in favour of `varbinary` btw.

Comment: @Fabio Yes I am aware , but what I am seeing is not the content of the byte array, but the string : <Binary Data>

Comment: @AlexK.Thank you for pointing this out, I will change the type

Comment: Yes, in Management Studio's "Table View" you will see `<Binary data>` for image/varbinary columns.  If you run a `SELECT` it will be displayed in hexadecimal format in the Results View.

Comment: @AlexK. alright , thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AlexK. pointed out,

> in Management Studio's "Table View" you will see  for image/varbinary columns. If you run a SELECT it will be displayed in hexadecimal format in the Results View

and @Yogi noted:

> Please note that Image data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work. Use varbinary(max) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is going to store the image as binary data from 0 through 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647) bytes.

Please note that Image data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work. Use `varbinary(max)` instead.  ([Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))

Comment: oh thank you for the info, I am not sure I was clear enough in my question though. What I am seeing is not the byte array but the string : <Binary Data>(I will change the type to varbinary(max) but I need to know.. Thank you